# How to select only few columns in scikit learn column selector pipeline?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I was reading the scikitlearn tutorial about column transformer. The given example (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.make_column_selector.html#sklearn.compose.make_column_selector) works, but when I tried to select only few columns, It gives me error.

## MWE

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.compose import make_column_selector

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')
mycols = ['tip','sex']


ct = make_column_transformer(make_column_selector(pattern=mycols)
ct.fit_transform(df)
```

## Required

I want only the select columns in the output.

**NOTE**
Of course, I know I can do `df[mycols]`, I am looking for scikit learn pipeline example.

Comment: Whats your scikit and python versions?

Comment: `sklearn.__version__ # '0.22.2.post1'`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you don't mind `mlxtend`, it has built-in transformer for that.

## Using mlxtend

```
from mlxtend.feature_selection import ColumnSelector

pipe = ColumnSelector(mycols)
pipe.fit_transform(df)
```

## For sklearn >= 0.20

- Reference: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html

```py
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')
mycols = ['tip','sex']

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ("selector", ColumnTransformer([
        ("selector", "passthrough", mycols)
    ], remainder="drop"))
])

pipeline.fit_transform(df)
```

## For sklearn < 0.20

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

class FeatureSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, columns):
        self.columns = columns

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return X[self.columns]


pipeline = Pipeline([('selector', FeatureSelector(columns=mycols))
                     ])

pipeline.fit_transform(df)[:5]
```

Comment: But `mlextend`'s `ColumnSelector` doesn't work good when followed by encoders in the Pipeline. Writing custom estimator for that had solved in my case, where I could get the column names which is required for the numeric & categorical pieplines.

Answer (score 12):

I'm maybe a bit late, but you can also select columns using sklearn's `ColumnTranformer()` by setting the transformer to "passthrough" and `remainder='drop'`:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline


pipe = Pipeline([
    ("selector", ColumnTransformer([
        ("selector", "passthrough", mycols)
    ], remainder="drop"))
])
```